# watch command in python subprocess to print only the change in output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I do use python subprocess module to get a status of an kubernetes application as follow:

```
command = gravity status | grep -o 'Cluster status:.*' | cut -f2- -d:

def run_cmd(command):
    process  = subprocess.Popen(command,shell=True, universal_newlines=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = process.communicate()
    return out, err;
```

> `out:                active`

Does generate the output 'active' or 'degraded' but I would like to implement a `'watch'` so will print only when does change the `'active' to 'degraded'` and `'degraded' to 'active'` not to run every couple minutes to provide me the status.

> Question: how I can do this in python as a script or it is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
a=1
while a==1:
        out = subprocess.Popen('date', 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
        time.sleep(2)
        out2 = subprocess.Popen('date', 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
        if out != out2:
                print (out)
```